# Redirect to another page to a particular section

Tags: html

I am creating a portfolio website for practice purpose.

***index.html :***

[image]

***work.html :***

[image]

In index.html, the three sections at bottom are images. On clicking either one, it redirects to work.html
In work.html , the three sections have separate ids as #website-container, #ui_ux-container & #business_cards-container. And the line is a normal `<hr>` tag.

My question is, since **work.html** will be a long page, how can I redirect to a particular section from one page to another ?

I tried doing :

`<a target="#website-container" href="work.html">
    <img src="websites.png">
</a>`

but this opened the **work.html** on a separate tab. how can I make it open in same tab and in that particular section ?

Comment: put the target on the end of the url (if there is an id with matching the hash, then it will jump straight to that section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get you right, you just have to change your code to

```html
<a href="work.html#website-container">
    <img src="websites.png">
</a>
```

so its an link with an anchor (directly after the "normal" url '**e.g. your-url.html#anchor**')... if the ID is set correctly you'll directly jump to that position

Answer (score 0):

Href should be work.html#website-container remove target